# Aggregate SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

Question: What is the name of each customer, how many orders have they placed, and how many pizzas have they ordered?

[image]

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, Count(Orders.ID) AS NumberOfOrders, Count(Pizza.ID) AS NumberOfPizzas 
 FROM ((Customer LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON Customer.ID = Orders.CustomerID) LEFT OUTER JOIN Pizza ON Orders.ID = Pizza.OrderID) GROUP BY Customer.ID;
```

This is what it prints:

[image]

The number of orders is wrong, it should be 1-0-2-1.

When I change from "Orders.ID = Pizza.OrderID" to "Pizza.OrderID = Orders.ID" it will print out the number of orders for both columns instead of the number of pizzas for both columns.

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Please don't use images; copy the material into the question and format it as 'code'.  Copy the material into the question, ignoring the preview.  Make sure it looks correct and contains no tabs.  Select it, and indent it with the **`{}`** button above the edit box.  Now look at the preview and check it is still OK.  If you like, you can add an unindented line containing `<!-- language: lang-none -->` on its own before the example(s).  Your screen shots are nearly illegible — at least to the eyes of antiquities like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to `count(distinct orders.id)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're taking a class and learning, so I've got some extra feedback for you. First, if you are joining tables together, it is good practice to fully qualify each field you select even if it is unique to only a single table (e.g. `FirstName` becomes `c.FirstName`). It helps to self document your code.

Second, it is poor practice to have a field named the same thing in multiple tables if it does not mean the same thing. Specifically, `Customer.ID` should be `Customer.CustomerID`, and `Order.ID` should be `Order.OrderID`. Again, this helps self document not only your queries, but to every other developer that comes after you that has to use those tables. It is much clearer what exactly that ID field is representing.

The joins (at least in MySQL) do not have to all be wrapped in parentheses. Doing so when you don't have to can lead to frustrating typo errors and makes it harder for you and others to read.

Finally, for 99% of cases you should always use an ORDER BY clause in your final product because you can never rely on the program to give you back your results how you intend them. Choose something logical for the user. In this case, sorting by LastName then FirstName is pretty intuitive. Don't do things that annoy the user!

Now, onto your specific problem, it is pretty simple. You need to use a `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` in the query. Taking all of the above into account, I reordered your query to improve the readability of it. I hope this helps!

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) AS NumberOfOrders,
     COUNT(p.ID) AS NumberOfPizzas
FROM Customer c 
     LEFT JOIN Order o ON o.CustomerID = c.ID
     LEFT JOIN Pizza p ON p.OrderID = o.ID
GROUP BY c.ID
ORDER BY c.LastName, c.FirstName
```